# Adding up time durations in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I would like to add up a series of splits in Python. The times begin as strings like "00:08:30.291". I can't seem to find the right way to use the Python objects or API to make this convenient/elegant. It seems that the time object doesn't use microseconds, so I'm using datetime's strptime to parse the strings, successfully. But then datetimes don't seem to add, and I really prefer not to overflow into days (i.e. 23 + 2 hours = 25 hours). I can use datetime.time but they don't add either. Timedeltas would seem appropriate but seem a little awkward to convert from/to other things. Perhaps I am missing something obvious here. I would like to be able to:

```
for timestring in times:
    t = datetime.strptime("%H:%M:%S.%f", timestring).time
    total_duration = total_duration + t
print total_duration.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: *I prefer not to overflow into days*. What does this mean? what the 23 hours + 2 hours should equal to?

Comment: @SilentGhost: I would assume just a lot of hours, i.e. 25 in that case.

Comment: yes, preferably 25. consider that non-essential if you wish.

Comment: @Sam Brightman do you mean `duration.days*24*60*60 + duration.seconds`?  If you mean that, please write that in the question.

Comment: S.lott: I don't understand what you want me to clarify

Comment: What is 23 hours + 2 hours?  Is it 25 hours?  Yes or no?  Please update the question.  It would help to actually include the code that actually computes an answer you want, since it's just a trivial multiply and add; you could include the relevant day+second -> second calculation to make it perfectly clear what you want.

Comment: My question is about the awkwardness of the API, I can't understand why you've fixated on this despite me clarifying in the comment immediately. The accepted answer doesn't really avoid the awkwardness of manually pulling apart the structure and putting it into a new one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're working with is time differences, that's why using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is only appropriate here:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("00:08:30.291", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 8, 30, 291000)
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 2, 30, 291000)
>>> dt1 = datetime.timedelta(minutes=d1.minute, seconds=d1.second, microseconds=d1.microsecond)
>>> dt2 = datetime.timedelta(minutes=d2.minute, seconds=d2.second, microseconds=d2.microsecond)
>>> fin = dt1 + dt2
>>> fin
datetime.timedelta(0, 660, 582000)
>>> str(fin)
'0:11:00.582000'
```

Also, please don't use such names as `sum` for your variables, you're shadowing built-in.

Comment: Certainly works but inelegant pulling apart the structure and recreating, especially for prototyping. Is there a neater/quicker way using the current API? Feels like timedelta should have strptime or something.

Comment: I renamed the variable in the question.

Comment: Likewise it is excluded from strftime, and it is doesn't seem simple to convert between even datetime and date/time: d1.time is still a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

# read file with one duration per line
with open('clean_times.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read()

# Convert string to list of '00:02:12.31'
# I had to drop last item (empty string)
tmp = x.split('\n')[:-1]

# get list of ['00', 02, '12.31']
tmp = [i.split(':') for i in tmp.copy()]

# create numpy array with floats
np_tmp = np.array(tmp, dtype=np.float)

# sum via columns and divide
# hours/24 minutes/60 milliseconds/1000
# X will be a float array [days, hours, seconds]
# Something like `array([ 0.        , 15.68333333,  7.4189    ])`
X = np_tmp.sum(axis=0) / np.array([24, 60, 1000])
```

I was hapy here, but if you need fancy string like `'15:41:07.518'`
as output, continue reading

```py
# X will be a float array [hours, hours, seconds]
X = np_tmp.sum(axis=0) / np.array([1, 60, 1000])

# ugly part
# Hours are integer parts
H = int(X[0]) + int(X[1])
# Minutes are  hour fractional part and integer minutes part
tmp_M = (X[0] % 1 + X[1] % 1) * 60
M = int(tmp_M)
# Seconds are minutes fractional part and integer seconds part
tmp_S = tmp_M % 1 * 60 + X[2]
S = int(tmp_S)
# Milliseconds are seconds fractional part
MS = int(tmp_S % 1 * 1000)

# merge string for output
# Something like '15:41:07.518'
result = f'{H:02}:{M:02}:{S:02}.{MS:03}'
```