# How to convert duration time format into seconds?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a dataset that shows how long an employee was on the phone for with the employee name etc. In the following format: Hr:Min:Sec

[image: Original Data]

I want to group the data by Employee_Name so that it shows the following:

[image: Expected Outcome]

or even in Seconds.

```
CallLogs.groupby(['Employee_Name'])['Duration_Of_Call'].agg('sum')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 
'datetime.time'
```

Comment: what is the `dtype` of that column? Dates and times in pandas should be stored with `np.datetime64` and `np.timedelta64` not datetime. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Comment: The `time` type in `datetime` references a specific point during the day, if you want to add durations you should use the `timedelta` type.

Comment: initially it was an object and i used  pd.to_datetime to convert it to a datetime and then used .dt.time to keep the timestamp only.

Comment: @cmmcd the col of 'call_duration' is an already calculated col reflecting the duration of a call. so its not an actual time sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The error shows the type as `datetime.time` not `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: you can't add two datetime objects. take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410454/adding-up-time-durations-in-python.
you can convert it to timedelta and then easily add it.
 hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a Timedelta column instead of a datetime column. Then you can add multiple values.

Something like:

```
CallLogs['Duration_Of_Call'] = pd. to_timedelta(CallLogs['Duration_Of_Call'])
CallLogs.groupby(['Employee_Name'])['Duration_Of_Call'].agg('sum')
```